# Facebook post using open graph for test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to post using facebook open graph for test user account. But I am getting the error "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."

I read this "Just a head's up, not sure if it's a change, however unsubmitted Open Graph action types (i.e. review) can only be tested with an app Administrator or Developers account. Test accounts won't work" on http://railscasts.com/episodes/363-facebook-open-graph?view=comments#comment_161576

Could someone please let me know if I can solve this?

Edit:
As suggested here is the description:
I have a website which uses facebook login and then user can post some of their action on facebook which uses facebook object graph.

What I want:
User from my website can post some thing on facebook.

What I have done:
Code :

```
   function postToWall() {

    FB.api(
   'https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.watches',
   'post',
  { video: '<A Valid Link>',
   message : msg,

     privacy: {'value': 'EVERYONE'}},
   function(response) {
     if (!response) {
     document.getElementById("result-msg").innerHTML="There is some problem with communication. Please try again!!!";
     $('#result-msg').fadeIn('slow').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
     } else if (response.error) {
     console.log(response.error.code);
       document.getElementById("result-msg").innerHTML="All is not well !! "+response.error.message;
        $('#result-msg').fadeIn('slow').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
     } else {
     document.getElementById("result-msg").innerHTML="Done!!! This has been posted. Keep listening!";
        $('#result-msg').fadeIn('slow').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
     }
```

Testing:
I have tested using my account and it works fine. Just to add I am admin of the app.
Also have tested using my spouse' account and it works fine again. She has been added as Tester of the app.

I have also created 3 test users account (Facebook Test User) as doc says that I need to test my action wit facebook test user. But it does not work for facebook test user.
I always get this msg "All is not well !! An unexpected error has occured. Please try again later"

Technology Used: HTML/Javascript, PHP

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I've explained you on the FB Developers group, it is not possible to anyone to understand your problem, because you're just only saying:

"I'm doing X and not getting Result Y". Without any additional information. Start with this:

1. What do you want to do? The whole use-case scenario
2. What kind of Test user did you create? Why not using your own profil? As I know there is no "test account" on facebook. You're creating a normal profile, except that you're creating it only test something.
3. What technology stack are you using? (Ruby, Nodejs, etc.) with which Frameworks / Libraries (Rails, Express, Passportjs etc.).
4. Your application is realizing a POST to the Facebook Graph API, so show as the code you use for this call and how your HTTP POST call looks like. Maybe you're missing a token or something.

cheers.

Comment: Did you activated your app for the general public? [link](http://developers.facebook.com) -> Your App -> "Status&Review" -> Toggle the button, but you should know that after this, theoretically everyone is able to use your app. Or you can just add other users in "Roles"

Comment: sry for the late response, but are you sure that you can post stuff with a test user account? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/test-user/ There is no entry given for posting messages.

Comment: This is what i found in facebook submission process https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/ "Before you can submit an action for review, you must publish it from within your app with the test user created during the submission process called the Open Graph Preview User. Do not submit your app for approval until you can successfully publish actions to the timeline of this test user"

Comment: Dou you want to submit new Actions ? Than you have to follow these rules : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/ I thought you only want to push simple standard "POST" messages and not your own open graph actions

Answer (score 0):

i just created an app like what you are trying to do you need
publish_actions permissions
i also had to go ahead and make my app live to work. and i had to extend the tokens.

Comment: Can you extended and clarify your answer?

Answer (score 0):

i use this code all the time and my users are all test users, all my info is pulled from the db but this should more than get you headed in the right direction. Make sure your app is live! Get an extended access token on the user or you wont be able to post to thier wall

```
 // require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
 require_once("facebook.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'appid';
$config['secret'] = 'appsecret';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);
 // define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array( "access_token" => $token, // see:       
"message" => "message",
"link" => "link",
"picture" => "picture",
"name" => "name",
"caption" => "caption",
"description" => "desc"
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
$ret = $fb->api('/'.$fbid.'/feed', 'POST', $params);


 } catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
```

Comment: sorry you need facebook.php and base_facebook.php

Comment: and of course i used php, i was looking at what you put here for code i really dont know how that worked on any account, if you need help with login for extended token just ask